# Running powershell scripts from Python without reimporting modules on every run

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, powershell-2.0

I am creating a Python script that calls a Powershell script `script.ps1` that needs to import the Active-Directory module.  However, every time I run the powershell script using 
`check_output('powershell.exe -File script.ps1')`
it needs to re-import the active directory module for each run of script.ps1, which makes the run time take about 3 seconds longer then it needs to.

I was wondering then, if there was a way to keep the Powershell module imported (as if it were being ran directly from Powershell, and not from Python) so that I can use things like

```
if(-not(Get-Module -name ActiveDirectory)){
  Import-Module ActiveDirectory
}
```

to speed up execution time.

Comment: What version of PowerShell?

Comment: You could make the "Host Profile" Load it when powershell is loaded

Comment: @Luke that won't save any time though, which is the stated purpose of this. You'd just be changing *where* the module is imported every time.

Comment: Can you feed individual commands to powershell's stdin? Then use subprocess.popen(stdin=PIPE)?

Comment: @briantist I am using Powershell 2

Comment: @briantist if it only calls the host once though....wait if it only called it once we wouldn't be here, so the script is closing the powershell instance instead of keeping it alive. Luke is there some way you can have python keep the powershell instance open?

Comment: That's a real shame @LukeD, as I think I have a solution but it requires PS 3 or higher. I might post it anyway, even though it probably won't help you. :-/

Comment: @Robᵩ, Powershell can take commands on stdin, but it will likely wait for all of the input before it executes any of it.

Comment: What is the Python doing? could you transform all of it to Powershell?

Comment: @Luke Python is hosting a Flask webapp that is being used to search active directory information for users.  Because my current solution requires reimporting the `ActiveDirectory` module on every run, searches are very slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution uses PowerShell remoting, and requires that the machine you remote into has the ActiveDirectory module, and it requires that the machine making the remote connection (the client) be PowerShell version 3 or higher.

In this example, the machine remotes into itself.

This would be your script.ps1 file:

```psh
#requires -Version 3.0

$ExistingSession = Get-PSSession -ComputerName . | Select-Object -First 1

if ($ExistingSession) {
    Write-Verbose "Using existing session" -Verbose
    $ExistingSession | Connect-PSSession | Out-Null
} else {
    Write-Verbose "Creating new session." -Verbose
    $ExistingSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName . -ErrorAction Stop
    Invoke-Command -Session $ExistingSession -ScriptBlock { Import-Module ActiveDirectory }
}

Invoke-Command -Session $ExistingSession -ScriptBlock {
    # do all your stuff here
}

$ExistingSession | Disconnect-PSSession | Out-Null
```

It takes advantage of PowerShell's support for disconnected sessions. Each time you shell out to PowerShell.exe, you end up connecting to an existing session with the ActiveDirectory module already loaded.

Once you're done with all the calls, you should destroy the session:

```psh
Get-PSSession -ComputerName . | Remove-PSSession
```

This was tested with a separate powershell.exe invocation on every run.

I do wonder if the cause for your delays is actually because of loading the ActiveDirectory module though, or if at least a significant portion of the delays are caused merely by having to load PowerShell.exe itself.

Comment: Just edited in the last line of code that missed my original copy/paste; it's very important! If you don't disconnect the session then it will be removed when the local session closes.

Comment: Nice bit of lateral thinking. +1

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work with Powershell v2, but it is a good solution.  I was wondering if it were possible to do a similar thing in Python by reconnecting to an existing Powershell session using Python a la `pexpect` (which, sadly, doesn't work on Windows)

Comment: Thanks gymbrall. @LukeD, I don't think there is a way to do that in python. Your options are limited since you're shelling out to powershell. I don't know how important this script is, or how big of a part of your organization it is, but I would probably consider writing a web service in ASP.NET that exposes specific REST API calls and behind the scenes talks to AD (even if it does so with PowerShell through a runspace). At that point you can use python (*or anything else*) to consume the REST API directly. Might sound like overkill but it has advantages.

Comment: I might be able to do something like what you have but with reconnecting to the session via ssh.  In the mean time, I'll mark this as the answer, because my situation is a bit of an edge case.